# Concatenate multiple files without header

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have several directories ("amazon", "niger",...), in which I have several subdirectories ("gfdl", "hadgem",...), in which I also have several sub-directories ("rcp8p5", "rcp4p5",...). In this last subdirectories I always have two folders ("historical", "projected") that contain thousand of tables having the same frame.
Therefore, I would like to concatenate those tables (present in the two folders of the last sub-directories) in order to have just one big table with only one header and not an header each time that a table has been concatenate. Does anyone knows how to do that?

I am currently using the following loop structure:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage:cat_dat dirname

data_dir=/scratch/01/stevens/climate_scenario/river

for river in tagus
  do
   for gcm in gfdl-esm2m hadgem2-es
     do
      for scenario in rcp8p5 rcp4p5 rcp6p0 rcp2p6
        do
          find "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}" name \*.dat -exec cat {} + >> "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}.dat"
      done
   done
done
```

but I can´t get rid of the header with that! Any helps is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: I have thousand of tables, all of them have the same header, I just want to concatenate them (group them in one unique table) and just keeping the header at the first line.

Comment: You can for example use `tail -n +2 file` to start printing the file from the 2nd line. Do it for all files but the first one.

Comment: ok, but where can I inplement that in my cmmand line: "ind "/dir/folder" name *.dat -exec cat tail -n +2 {} +  >> "/dir/folder/table.txt" Is that correct?

Comment: It is still unclear what exactly you want to do. For every pair of historical,projected dirs, to print just the first header and not print the rest? So if you have path1/subpath1/{historical,protected} and path1/subpath2/{historical,protected} you would want the first header in path1/subpath1/ and the first one in path2/subpath2/?

Comment: In fact I need to group the table present in path1/subpath1/{historical,projected} as one big table having just one header in the first line. And so on, for the next path path1/subpath2/{historical,projected} group the table present in one big table keeping the header in first line... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` in a single folder

```
awk 'NR==1 {header=$_} FNR==1 && NR!=1 { $_ ~ $header getline; } {print}' *.dat > out
```

`find` and `awk`  if you need all files in the current folder and in the subfolders. You can replace `.` with your desired folder.

```
find . -type f -name "*.dat" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 awk 'NR==1 {header=$_} FNR==1 && NR!=1 { $_ ~ $header getline; } {print}' > out
```

or, as [getline is bad](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) (thx [@fedorqui](https://askubuntu.com/users/143251/fedorqui))

```
find . -type f -name "*.dat" -exec awk 'NR==1 || FNR!=1' {} + ;
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo1.dat 
a   b   c
1   2   3

% cat foo2.dat
a   b   c
4   5   6

% awk 'NR==1 {header=$_} FNR==1 && NR!=1 { $_ ~ $header getline; } {print}' *.dat > out

% cat out 
a   b   c
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Comment: using getline is [quite overkilling](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline), see my answer. Also, what if the files are in different directories? This will just work for files in the current dir.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop that gets fed by a `find` through [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
d=0
while IFS= read -r file
do
   [ "$d" -ge 1 ] && tail -n +2 "$file" || cat "$file"
   (( d ++ ))
done < <(find "/dir/folder" name *.dat)
```

So it will perform a `cat` on the first match and `tail -n +2` on the rest.

---

Alternatively, if you have all the files in the same dir you can say:

```
awk 'FNR>1 || NR==1' files*
```

This will match everything but the case when `FNR==1` and `NR>1`, that is, everything but the header of the files after the first one. Why? Because `NR` holds the number of line being read overall, whereas `FNR` holds the number of line of the current file being read.

Comment: I think I have been unclear because it´s not really working. I have several directories ("amazon", "niger",...) each of them have subdirectories ("gfdl", "hadgem",...), who also have subdirectories ("rcp8p5", "rcp4p5",...) inside this last subdirectories I always have two directories ("historical" and "projection"), those two directories are composed by thousand of table (having the same frame), therefore I would like to combine those thousand tables (from those two last directories) in one unique table having only one header. Any other hints is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Just for info I am currently using the following loop:
#!/bin/bash
# usage:cat_dat dirname
data_dir=/home/stevens/climate_analysis
for river in amazon
  do
   for gcm in gfdl-esm2m hadgem2-es
     do
      for scenario in rcp8p5 rcp4p5
        do
          find "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${scenario}" -name \*.dat >> "${data_dir}/${river}/${gcm}/${river}_${gcm}_${scenario}.dat"
        done
   done
done

Comment: @steve you should update your question with all these details, as A.B. already asked you in the first place.

Comment: Ok I am sorry about that!